# How to open android app in PC browser with http protocol?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile-development

First, I don't know how to call this in android development. I am trying to search on the internet but found nothing.
Scenario:

- I develop an android app that could do database functions e.g. create, update, delete some data. Say simple list of animal names. I could do everything database functions but only on android device (I mean my app).

My question:

- Could I do all the database functions on PC browser that connected to my android app with a url link?

For example -- http://192.168.1.1:7575/

Link above will open a user interface that connected to my app and I could do database functions on it. If I change the data then it will change the data on android app as well.

Btw, I'm not native english speaker. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

See this image below: The right side is an android app that running on android device. The left side is web version that connected to the android device with a url. If I close the app on android, the web version also unavailable. It's only one app, an android app. I don't know how to achieve this ability.
[link here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gentatekno.app.portable.kasirtoko)

[image: Cashier App]

Comment: Yes this is possible. From your pc you could receive data from and post data to your Android app. All with a webpage. But its to your Android app what it does with the data. Your app could put it in a database or file or whatever. Your pc can only post/send data. It cannot execute database functions for your app.

Comment: There is not much to see. But you said you wanted to use `For example -- http://192.168.1.1:7575/` well that implies you have to instal a webserver on your Android device to begin with. And then added code to the webserver to handle GET and POST.

Comment: Do you mean an embedded webserver, like XAMPP that runs on Android app, right?
Is this hard to achieve it? I'm interested in this kind of feature that I can implement in my app.

Comment: For Android you could start with NanoHttpd webserver and add your logic. You could also install from play store a php webserver on your Android device and then write php scripts which do all. No need for an Android app then.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 4.1+ you can use the `Database Inspector` feature.
This feature lets you to see live update of the database, or manipulate the data.

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database

Comment: Could you see my edited question. Thanks.